# Django filter related_name subset in templates

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have a foreign key and I'm using the related_name field like so:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
   ...
   restaurant = models.ForeignKey('Restaurant', related_name='pizzas_offered')
   active = models.BooleanField(...)
   ...
```

Example from the view:

```
my_restaurant = get_object_or_404(Restaurant, pk=id)
```

In any template I can run something like **my_restaurant.pizzas_offered.all** to get all the pizzas belonging to a particular restaurant. However, I only want the pizzas that are active (active=True). Is there a way to retrieve this subset in the template, without having to pass a separate variable in the view? Please note that I *always* want to only show the active pizzas only so if I have to make a change in the model to make this happen, that is fine too.

NOTE: in the view I can simply pass **my_restaurant.pizzas_offered.filter(active=True)** but it returns an error when I use it in the template:

```
{% for details in my_restaurant.pizzas_offered.filter(active=True) %}
  {{ details.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

It returns this error:
*Could not parse the remainder: '(active=True)'*

There are some reasons why I want to do this on template level and not in the view (main reason: I often loop through all the records in the database and not just one restaurant, so I can't just query for the one record). So my question is how to do this on template-level.

Comment: give `my_restaurant.pizzas_offered.filter(active=True)`

Comment: That works in views but not in templates...

Comment: Be precise.
Post your view.

Comment: Please note that my question is how to do this in a template, not in a view.

Comment: you can send the queried items in the view context  or create a template tag to filter like so

Comment: If we don't see your queryset how can we know how to do that in your template? Post that at least.

Comment: I have expanded the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create a `Manager` for your `Pizza` model and set the [`Meta.base_manager_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.base_manager_name):

```
class PizzaManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(status=True)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = PizzaManager()

    class meta:
        base_manager_name = 'objects'
```

Now you can use the method `active` in your template:

```
{% for details in my_restaurant.pizzas_offered.active %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

For more information you can read the documentation about [Default and Base managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#default-managers).